# ssis not showing all schemas or tables present in snowflake, after connecting it to snowflake through odbc driver

Tags: sql-server, ssis, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, sql-server-data-tools, snowflake-schema

I have ssis software(Microsoft SQL Server 2017 Data Tools 15.9.2) installed on our machines. we are not able to see all schemas after connecting it to snowflake through odbc driver. although i am able to see all schemas on older version but due to some problem, we can't use it. do anyone can help me with this issue.

Comment: What version of ODBC driver are you using and do you see any errors in the ODBC generic log?

Comment: SnowflakeDSIIDriver, Version: 2.22.05.00, snowflake hosted on azure @Sergiu

Answer (score 0):

Quoting yourself as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66022583/snowflake-role-error-while-connecting-using-python), maybe you just made a very slight mistake(single character mistake)?